# moving text in video with ffmpeg always 3 minute

Tags: video, ffmpeg, convert

I have a problem. I have found a tutorial on how to add text in videos using ffmpeg. but I want every 3 minute. I get the script only 10 second 1 time. I want 3 minute 1 time.

my script:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSans.ttf:text='Hello World':fontcolor=white@1.0:fontsize=16:y=h-line_h-100:x=w/10*mod(t\,10):enable=gt(mod(t\,20)\,10)" -codec:v libx264 -codec:a copy -y output.mp4
```

source of : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737643/ffmpeg-moving-text-to-appear-every-x-seconds)

help me setting always 3 minute and speed text 10 second

please ask for an explanation from each script above and please help so that every 1 minute the text appears

thank you

Comment: You may be interested in the editor `kdenlive` or `melt` program.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
enable='gt(mod(t,60),57)'
```

This means: every 57 seconds for 3 seconds.